# Cancel an onclick event if I highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that, when clicked, I want to an action to happen.

That div contains some text.

If the user highlights the text (e.g. they are trying to copy/paste, rather than actually click it) then I want to *cancel the onclick event* so that the action doesn't happen if they were just trying to highlight, not actually click.

Is there a way to do this with JQuery or plain old Javascript?

Comment: In the onclick event, check if text is selected. If so, abort. ???

Comment: Why are you assuming that highlighting the text means they want to copy/paste?

Comment: I think you would want to check after `mouseup` if any text has been selected.

Comment: wait, if the user is successful at highlighting the text then he/she would of copied the text already and not clicked. If the user was unable to highlight the text and accidentally clicked, then the text is not highlighted. I don't understand the use case

Comment: @Ian it may not mean they want to copy text. But it's **pretty darn hard** to copy specific text *without* highlighting first. :)

Comment: @ErikE Very true. I guess the OP has "e.g.", so they weren't **only** referring to copy/paste

Comment: @PalashMondal jQuery *is* JavaScript.  The question is perfectly legitimate, the tag indicates that vanilla JS or jQuery is acceptable.

Comment: @Huangism What do you mean, "if the user is successful at highlighting the text then... copied ... already"? The act of highlighting (mousedown->drag->mouseup[click]) is the *exact thing* that causes the `onclick` to occur, *before* any copy action can be performed.

Comment: well it's not clear if OP wants a jquery solution since he specifically said javascript, anyway this is minor

Comment: I am on a mac, I cannot highlight the text in an anchor link starting in the middle of the link text. I could however start with one end and highlight to the middle of the link and it does not trigger any click event

Comment: @Huangism What link text? No one said anything about a hyperlink or `<a>` element. It's just a `div`.

Comment: well divs that's a different story

Comment: @PalashMondal If some poor sucker gives a plain-vanilla javascript answer because he misses that the question is tagged `jQuery`, too, that won't exactly hurt anything, will it?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the question is. If they're asking about Javascript, and tag jQuery as well, both are fair game. Since jQuery *is* Javascript, the question doesn't need to change and it's not even that important. jQuery is tagged, so it can be used in an answer validly

Comment: it's always possible that the jquery tag was a mistake, since lot of people knows javascript and does not know jquery, let's have the OP edit the question to end this discussion

Comment: Please everyone remove your comments here, not related to the question..

Comment: Edited - I don't care if it's plain old javascript or uses the JQuery lib. As long as it works, I'm happy. :-)

Comment: Think is is a duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712310/javascript-how-to-detect-if-a-word-is-highlighted

Answer (score 2):

Try detecting the onmouseup event:

```
document.onmouseup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;
```

If the text is highlighted, you will have a value in window.getSelection use that to determine what kind of event you should be firing.

Check out this post / fiddle:

[Javascript: How to detect if a word is highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712310/javascript-how-to-detect-if-a-word-is-highlighted)
http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/SW54T/