# Get Selected Text on HTML page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangy

I have a simple HTML page where I want the selected text inside text area to use it for some processing. I have written jQuery code but I am always getting empty string as selection. Please help me to fix this issue in my code.

HTML code is as given below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" id="formfirst">
        <textarea name="tafirst" rows="10" id="tafirst">Along came Polly ---- Reality Bites ---- Duplex ---- Walter Mitty </textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="txtfirst">
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/verify.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript code is given below:(verify.js)

```
function getSelectedText(){
    var t = '';
    if(window.getSelection){
        t = window.getSelection();
    }else if(document.getSelection){
        t = document.getSelection();
    }else if(document.selection){
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}

$(document).ready(function(){  
    //alert("HERE 1");
});
$(document).keypress(function(e){   
    if($('#tafirst').is(':focus')){
        if(e.altKey && e.which==97){
            alert(getSelectedText());
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I have downloaded rangy plugin and put it inside my js folder. I have included that plugin in my HTML as given below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rangy/rangy-1.2.3/rangy-core.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" id="formfirst">
<textarea name="tafirst" rows="10" id="tafirst">Along came Polly ---- Reality Bites ---- Duplex ---- Walter Mitty </textarea>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtfirst">
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/verify.js"></script>
</html>
```

Corresponding modified js file is as follows:

```
var range = rangy.createRange();

$(document).ready(function(){  
    alert(range);
    alert("HERE 1");    
});
$(document).keypress(function(e){   
    if($('#tafirst').is(':focus')){
        if(e.altKey && e.which==97){
            alert(getSelectedText());
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

But it is not even showing any alert message. Have I done anything wrong while adding rangy's js reference?

Comment: Try using the [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) plugin by Tim Down. Getting the selected text is a cross-browser nightmare.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan:Edited code to use rangy plugin. It is not working. Please help me to correct my code.

Comment: Getting the selected text is pretty easy, although the code to do it in the question (`getSelectedText`) is not correct because it returns a `Selection` object rather than a string in most browsers. [Here is some better code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4713197/96100). Rangy uses the same basic method anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting selected text from a textarea requires a different API from getting the selected text in the main text of the page in most browsers. You should use the textarea's `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties. This method will work for text inputs too:

```
function getSelectedText(el) {
    var sel, range;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        return el.value.slice(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
    } else if (
            (sel = document.selection) &&
            sel.type == "Text" &&
            (range = sel.createRange()).parentElement() == el) {
         return range.text;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Example:

```js
function getSelectedText(el) {
  var sel, range;
  if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
    return el.value.slice(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
  } else if (
    (sel = document.selection) &&
    sel.type == "Text" &&
    (range = sel.createRange()).parentElement() == el) {
    return range.text;
  }
  return "";
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("ta").onselect = function() {
    alert("Selected text: " + getSelectedText(this));
  };
};
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" rows="5" cols="50">Please select some text in here</textarea>
```