# Check if a text input content is selected (highlighted)

Tags: javascript, jquery, selected, textinput

How do I check if a specific text input in a form is selected (highlighted)?
Can I do it with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712310/javascript-how-to-detect-if-a-word-is-highlighted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712310/javascript-how-to-detect-if-a-word-is-highlighted)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
input:focus { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selected = $(':focus');
```

Comment: Would this apply to all input types, password etc?

Comment: try fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8zjtce2p/1/

Comment: Iam better off with pure javascript :P thanks anyway ^

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want input types text. Here is a javascript solution.

```
function addevents() {
   var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
      input[i].addEventListener('focus', focus, false);
}

function focus() {
    if(this.type === 'text')
        alert(this + ' iam a text input');
}

addevents();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected input text using following jQuery statement:

```
$("input[type='text']:focus")
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v7hfp48d/