# Popup on table row text highlight (only) i

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a table with multiple rows. Each column has some text in it. I want to create a popup when any part of string text is selected/highlighted. I researched entire web but unable to find a solution. Can someone help?

Comment: This is not a site to request code from others. Instead, you should research this topic and attempt to solve the problem on your own; if there is a specific issue that you are unable to resolve in the process, come back and present it and we can help you out.

Comment: Hey Tristan, I am new to front end. I tried this before but I was successful in getting popup on text highlight but not specific to table. Hence I tot I could seek somehelp. Thanks for sharing your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('table').on('mouseup', function(){
  var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  if (selectedText) {
    alert('Some text was selected');
  }
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZoxZB

Comment: Hey Mark. This works like a charm. I need to display a popover right above the text highlighted.          

<div id="infoDiv" class="tooltipDiv">
    // content goes here
</div>

I am new to front end. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Same question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712310/javascript-how-to-detect-if-a-word-is-highlighted)

```
function getSelectedText() {
    var text = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

function doSomethingWithSelectedText() {
    var selectedText = getSelectedText();
    if (selectedText) {
        alert("Got selected text " + selectedText);
    }
}

document.onmouseup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;
document.onkeyup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;
```

Comment: Hey Zoheiry, I have tried this but div pops on highlight of anytext in the page. However, Mark's solution works. But I need the tip to be right above the text highlighted. Any help would be much appreciated. 


// HTML CODE HERE
 $('table').on('mouseup', function(){
          var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
          if (selectedText) {
            $('#infoDiv').css('display', 'block');
          }
  })

Comment: After getting the element that was selected you can get the position of the element like so. $(your-element).offset().top and $(your-element).offset().left. Now you have the top and left positions. You can display your popup in that same position