# When text selected, if equals same value as ID, run function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a variation of this [Javascript: How to detect if a word is highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712310/javascript-how-to-detect-if-a-word-is-highlighted) , but I'd like to run the function **getSelectedText** only if the selected text matches the value of the **h1 id**

The code I set looks like:

```
  function getSelectedText() {
      var x = document.getElementById("titleProduct");
      var text = "";
      if (typeof window.getSelection === x) {
          alert('hey');
          text = window.getSelection().toString();
      } 
      return text;
  }

  function doSomethingWithSelectedText() {
      var selectedText = getSelectedText();
      if (selectedText) {
         document.getElementById("hiddenCTA").className = "visibleCTA";
      }
  }

  var x = document.getElementById("titleProduct");
  document.onmouseup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;
```

I included the **alert('hey')** inside that **if** loop to see that is running, just for testing but there is no evidence of it in my tests, nor I can see any errors in the console. The whole code is in http://codepen.io/malditojavi/pen/LWmRvp?editors=1010

In this case, the function should only run if the full string 'Title Of Your Product' is selected, not any other text within the HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` should be:

```
if (window.getSelection().toString() === x.textContent) {
```

But it seems your function could just return a boolean indicating if the expected text was matched. As you already know the text in that case, it suffices to return true or false. Here is how I would suggest writing it:

```js
function isSelectedText(txt) {
    return window.getSelection().toString().trim() === txt;
}

function doSomethingWhenTextSelected() {
    if (isSelectedText(document.getElementById("titleProduct").textContent)) {
        document.getElementById("hiddenCTA").className = "visibleCTA";
    }
}

document.onmouseup = doSomethingWhenTextSelected;
```

```css
.hiddenCTA { display: none }
.visibleCTA { display: block }
```

```html
<h3 id="titleProduct">Title Of Your Product</h3>

hhhh

<div class="hiddenCTA" id="hiddenCTA">Hey, we do price match!</div>
```